# Use tkplot in igraph when matching vertex size to label

Tags: r, igraph, tkplot

I am trying to apply the script suggested in another post on this forum for matching vertex size to label: [Match vertex size to label size in igraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472079/match-vertex-size-to-label-size-in-igraph/19097133). 
The solution for the plot function works perfectly but the same syntax cannot be used for the tkplot function. Replacing plot by tkplot returns an error message. I need to use the latter one because my figure has many vertexes and too long vertex labels, and i want to be able to readjust the positions of the vertexes manually. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer to your question, but a workaround. Use `tkplot()` to plot your vertices, adjust the vertex positions, then query the positions with `tkplot.getcoords()`, and use the returned coordinates in `plot()`.