# igraph rectange vertices connect on the "wrong" side

Tags: r, igraph

I am struggling to find a setting that will prevent rectangular vertices to connect on the wrong (aka remote) side. For directed graphs, the problem is both for outgoing and incoming sides of the edges.

Borrowing example from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14473972/1114163, if we adjust transparency of the vertices the problem becomes apparent

[image]

For example, Don-Steve and Steve-Gery edges go through Don and Steve, respectively. I have not seen it happening with circles, but I would like to fix it also for rectangles, as these are particularly useful for networks with longer text labels... (note, the problem is not specific to resized vertices, the same problem can be seen when setting fixed widths for rectangles)

```
camp <- graph.formula(Harry:Steve:Don:Bert - Harry:Steve:Don:Bert,
    Pam:Brazey:Carol:Pat - Pam:Brazey:Carol:Pat,
    Holly   - Carol:Pat:Pam:Jennie:Bill,
    Bill    - Pauline:Michael:Lee:Holly,
    Pauline - Bill:Jennie:Ann,
    Jennie  - Holly:Michael:Lee:Ann:Pauline,
    Michael - Bill:Jennie:Ann:Lee:John,
    Ann     - Michael:Jennie:Pauline,
    Lee     - Michael:Bill:Jennie,
    Gery    - Pat:Steve:Russ:John,
    Russ    - Steve:Bert:Gery:John,
    John    - Gery:Russ:Michael)

V(camp)$label <- V(camp)$name
set.seed(42)   ## to make this reproducable
co <- layout.auto(camp)

plot(0, type="n", ann=FALSE, axes=FALSE, xlim=extendrange(co[,1]), 
    ylim=extendrange(co[,2]))
plot(camp, layout=co, rescale=FALSE, add=TRUE,vertex.color=adjustcolor("blue",.3),
    vertex.shape="rectangle",
    vertex.size=(strwidth(V(camp)$label) + strwidth("oo")) * 100,
    vertex.size2=strheight("I") * 2 * 100)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in `igraph` that was there for a very long time, but it has been fixed in the devel version on Github.

By design, the `"rectangle"` shape of node should have edges aimed at the centre of the node, but they stop when they hit the edge of the rectangle.  However, the bug meant that one of the 4 possible intersections of the edge with a side of the rectangle was not calculated properly, so the code would choose the second intersection on the far side.

There's no easy way to work around this while still using `"rectangle"` shapes with `igraph` 1.6.0 (current version on CRAN).  If you install the devel version of `igraph` from Github you'll get the fix, and eventually it will make it to CRAN.

If you want a partial solution sooner, you can choose shape `"crectangle"` instead.  That's almost the same as `"rectangle"`, but edges always aim for the centre of one of the sides of the rectangle.   Your example looks like this with that choice:

```r
library(igraph)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'igraph'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     decompose, spectrum
#> The following object is masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     union
camp <- graph.formula(Harry:Steve:Don:Bert - Harry:Steve:Don:Bert,
                      Pam:Brazey:Carol:Pat - Pam:Brazey:Carol:Pat,
                      Holly   - Carol:Pat:Pam:Jennie:Bill,
                      Bill    - Pauline:Michael:Lee:Holly,
                      Pauline - Bill:Jennie:Ann,
                      Jennie  - Holly:Michael:Lee:Ann:Pauline,
                      Michael - Bill:Jennie:Ann:Lee:John,
                      Ann     - Michael:Jennie:Pauline,
                      Lee     - Michael:Bill:Jennie,
                      Gery    - Pat:Steve:Russ:John,
                      Russ    - Steve:Bert:Gery:John,
                      John    - Gery:Russ:Michael)

V(camp)$label <- V(camp)$name
set.seed(42)   ## to make this reproduceable
co <- layout.auto(camp)

plot(0, type="n", ann=FALSE, axes=FALSE, xlim=extendrange(co[,1]), 
     ylim=extendrange(co[,2]))
plot(camp, layout=co, rescale=FALSE, add=TRUE,vertex.color=adjustcolor("blue",.3),
     vertex.shape="crectangle",
     vertex.size=(strwidth(V(camp)$label) + strwidth("oo")) * 100,
     vertex.size2=strheight("I") * 2 * 100)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Still needs some tweaking, in my opinion.  Shape `"vrectangle"` is another choice, but it looks even worse.

EDITED to add:

Based on @BBB's comment, here is a way to patch the current CRAN version so that it fixes the bug and works properly:

```r
library(igraph, quietly = TRUE, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
myrect <- shapes("rectangle")
clip <- myrect$clip

# The magic location below is found one entry at a time:
# print body(clip) first, guess at which entry needs the
# patch, then print body(clip)[[6]], guess again, continue
# as far as you want.  

location <- c(6,3,3,3,3,2,3,2)
oldcode <- body(clip)[[location]]

if (identical(oldcode, quote(vsize))) {
  body(clip)[[location]] <- quote(vsize2)
} else
  stop("Code is not as expected!")
  
add_shape("myrectangle", clip = clip, plot = myrect$plot)

g <- make_graph(c(1,2, 1,4, 2,1, 2,5, 2,3, 4,1, 5,2, 3,2))
layout <- cbind(c(-2.01, -1.16, -1.24, -2.74, -0.13),
                c(1.27, 2.1, 3.14, 0.56, 2.01))
plot(g,
     vertex.size = 30,
     vertex.color = rgb(0.1, 0.7, 0.8, 0.1),
     vertex.shape = "myrectangle",
     layout = layout
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: "Even sooner" solution was to include the fix to the typo identified on github into the clip function and then introduce "myrectangle" shape, where the clip function is the one without a typo :) I am a happy camper. (I do not like "crectangle" and "vrectangle" just like you). For others, who want it also sooner, change the first line of l definition to `x1 - vsize2 / m, y1 - vsize2,`

Comment: I showed how to change the code on the fly.

Comment: Note that almost all igraph functions with a dot in the name are deprecated. `graph.formula` should be `graph_from_literal`, `layout.auto` should be `layout_nicely`.